# Sorting an Array using Bucket Sort by length of String

Tags: java

Tried sorting an array of strings by length in java using bucket sort but I keep getting array index out of bounds

```
String[] bucketSort = new String[MAX_NAMES + 1];
for(int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
   bucketSort[names[i].length()] += 1; 
  }

  int outPos = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < bucketSort.length; i++) {
    if(bucketSort[i].length() > 0) {
     names[outPos++] = i; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: this shouldn´t even compile.

Comment: You should decide whether your arrays should contain Strings or ints. They can't contain both.